# How to correctly comment a DB query in a PHP application?

Tags: php

I am abslutly new in PHP and probably this is a very trivial question about how to correctly comment a line in a MySql query.

I have a query like this:

```
$query_hotel= "
    SELECT 
        hotel_name,
        hotel_id,
        room_id,
        ...................................
        ...................................
        ...................................
        FROM (
            ............................................
            ............................................
            )
            WHERE
                ...............................................
            HAVING
                //SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$price_min." AND ".$price_max."
                SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$min_price." AND ".$max_price."

    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
```

So, as you can see in my code, I have to comment (to disable) this line:

```
//SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$price_min." AND ".$price_max."
```

that have to be replaced by this line:

SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$min_price." AND ".$max_price."

I am not sure that using the **//** at the line start it's correct. I also tried to do:

```
<!--SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$price_min." AND ".$price_max."-->
```

but doing in this way my IDE (PHP Storm) is as disabled all but not the PHP variable.

So what is the correct way to do it without remove this line from my code? (I want to keep track of this changes and let it commented in my code)

Comment: If you want to keep track of your changes `use version control` `commented code == dead code` is not at all good practice to keep in the code.
Moreover you should comment your line using `--` i.e. SQL's way of identifying the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has two kinds of comments. A one-line comment uses the prefix `--`. You can also create a block comment by surrounding it with `/*` and `*/`.

MySQL also allows `#` as a comment prefix, this is an extension to the SQL standard.

```
$query_hotel= "
    SELECT 
        hotel_name,
        hotel_id,
        room_id,
        ...................................
        ...................................
        ...................................
        FROM (
            ............................................
            ............................................
            )
            WHERE
                ...............................................
            HAVING
                /* SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$price_min." AND ".$price_max." */
                SUM(rate.price) BETWEEN ".$min_price." AND ".$max_price."

    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
```